# should i use React-Bootstrap instead of Bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, meteor, reactjs, react-bootstrap

I'm trying to find any reason why should i use react-bootstrap:

```
<Row componentClass="header" className="panel panel-default">
    someBlocks
</Row>
```

Instead of just using bootstrap in jsx:

```
<header className="row panel panel-default">
    someColBlocks
</header>
```

Sometime it's even easier use just Bootstrap. Maybe i just don't know something?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Regular bootstrap relies on jquery for making things happen with dynamic elements.  In react this can become problematic, as you typically want to avoid directly mutating the DOM, and rather manage everything through changes in state/props.  The problem with mutating the DOM directly is it is generally slower than react's  DOM diffing, and it is harder to track down bugs.  The advantage of React-Bootstrap is that you can take advantage of the pre-built components / grid system of Bootstrap, while still following "best practices" within react.